# Wondering about the grammar of “we keep remaining confident”

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> "We are on his side during his long and difficult fight, together with the team of the hospital in Grenoble, and **we keep remaining confident**," Ms Kehm said.
> <sub>Source: [ABC News – Michael Schumacher: Formula One champion showing 'moments of consciousness' after skiing accident](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-04-04/michael-schumacher-showing-moments-of-consciousness/5369056)</sub>

Does **“we keep remaining confident”** mean **“we are continually remaining confident”**?

What grammar is used here? Could you provide me with some examples and also simplify them in order to clarify the issue?

Answer (score 2):

"We keep remaining confident" means essentially the same thing as "We remain confident". We were confident before, and we are still confident. "Keep" here is an intensifier, to make clear that we have not stopped being confident, the confidence is ongoing.

It is not quite the same grammatically as "We are continually remaining confident". That would indicate something that goes on indefinitely and constantly. "We keep remaining confident" means we were in the past and we still are now, but grammatically it does not say how often we have done this or whether we will continue to do it in the future.

I think it's a little redundant to say "continually remaining", as "continually" indicates it's an ongoing thing already.